# How to retrieve BOOLEANS with a custom sql query in Rails 3 + Postgres?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, boolean, coalesce

In my model I've made this custom sql query :

```
SELECT
    training_courses.id,
    training_courses.training_id,
    training_courses.course_id,
    training_courses.is_pre_test, 
    training_courses.order_by,
    training_course_histories.id AS training_course_history_id, 
    training_course_histories.finished_at,
    training_course_histories.score,
    CAST(coalesce(user_training_courses.id, 0) as BOOLEAN) as purchased
FROM
    training_courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN training_course_histories
        ON training_course_histories.training_course_id = training_courses.id AND training_course_histories.id = (
            SELECT th1.id
            FROM training_course_histories th1      
            WHERE th1.training_course_id = training_courses.id
              AND th1.finished_at IS NOT NULL
              AND th1.user_id = 1
            ORDER BY th1.finished_at DESC LIMIT 1
        )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_training_courses
        ON user_training_courses.training_course_id = training_courses.id AND user_training_courses.id = (
            SELECT th2.id
            FROM user_training_courses th2          
            WHERE th2.training_course_id = training_courses.id 
              AND th2.user_id = 1
        )
WHERE (training_courses.training_id = 1)
GROUP BY
    training_courses.id,
    training_courses.id,
    training_courses.training_id,
    training_courses.course_id,
    training_courses.is_pre_test, 
    training_courses.order_by,
    training_course_histories.id,
    training_course_histories.finished_at,
    training_course_histories.score, 
    user_training_courses.id
ORDER BY 
    order_by ASC, 
    id ASC, 
    training_courses.order_by ASC, 
    training_courses.id ASC
```

Before, I was using a Mysql database so, no problem at all, the query was like : `ISNULL(user_training_courses.id) as purchased`

But now, I'm using Postgres and I must have `CAST(coalesce(user_training_courses.id, 0) as BOOLEAN) as purchased`

The problem: for Rails, purchased = 't' or 'f' (strings)

What I want : purchased = true or false (booleans)

Is it possible ?

Thx.

Comment: The CAST as boolean is simply not working... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I rather have an accessor in my model to handle this case.

```
def purchased
  ![false, 'false', 'f', 'FALSE', 'F', 0, '0'].include?(self[:purchased])
end
```

Comment: You'd be better off with `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails PostgreSQL driver understands that PostgreSQL booleans come out as `'t'` and `'f'` and usually translates them properly. Your CAST:

```
CAST(coalesce(user_training_courses.id, 0) as BOOLEAN)
```

should also be fine:

```
psql=> select cast(11 as boolean), cast(1 as boolean), cast(0 as boolean);
 bool | bool | bool 
------+------+------
 t    | t    | f
```

So I'd guess that Rails just doesn't know the column type of your CAST. For example:

```
rails > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows('select cast(1 as boolean), 11 = 11')
 => [["t", "t"]]
```

You can convert the `'t'` and `'f'` to booleans yourself using the Set constants in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column`:

```
TRUE_VALUES = [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'].to_set
FALSE_VALUES = [false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE'].to_set
```

or you can use [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column/value_to_boolean/class):

```
rails > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows('select cast(1 as boolean), 11 = 11').map { |r| r.map { |b| ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(b) } }
 => [[true, true]]
```

But you'll still have to know what types all your columns are and sort things out by hand if you're going to use the low level SQL interface. Similar issues apply to integers, dates, and any other non-string types that you get back.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution. I understand that I'll have similar issues with other types... so I choose another way to convert 'f' and 't' to booleans.